# Can't deploy a contract via MyEtherWallet

Tags: contract-deployment, myetherwallet

I'm trying to deploy a contract on etherscan.io via MyEtherWallet. I copied bytecode and connected my Ledger Nano, but I can't sign transaction, gas input is not filling up automatically. There are no errors in console. It worked fine with test network.

Is it network problem?

Comment: What happens when you manually enter a gas amount that you know is sufficient?

Comment: I gave up blockchain